# Git merge not working but the response message is Already up to merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I have one branch `tasks-segment-export` when I switch on this branch I can see all my updates and everything is okey !

But when I switch to master and I try to merge `tasks-segment-export` it says `already up to date` but in fact not ! because I can't see the updates on my project (I have to switch to `tasks-segment-export` if I want to see my updates)

```
 (...)(master)
$ git merge tasks-segment-export
Already up to date.
```

How to merge `tasks-segment-export` into master  ?

Graph GITLAB: 
[image]

`$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate master tasks-segment-export` returns :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate master tasks-segment-export
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

`git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
*   0f5c91d (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merge branch 'tasks-segment-export' into 'master'
|\
| * fbd2302 (origin/tasks-segment-export, tasks-segment-export) sc2
* |   6e81272 (add-more-builders) head changes
|\ \
| * \   6f9f8ca Merge branch 'tmp-tasks-segment-export' into 'master'
| |\ \
| | * \   704ec13 Merge branch 'master' into 'tmp-tasks-segment-export'
| | |\ \
| | |/ /
| |/| /
| | |/
| * |   64763e3 merge conflict sol
| |\ \
| * | | ab4ef27 conflict
| * | |   ef2e418 solve conflict
| |\ \ \
| * \ \ \   37f9f5b Merge branch 'master' of gitlab.com:i-care-rd/irp-project
| |\ \ \ \
| | * \ \ \   45f57f9 Merge branch 'revert-e275fc4c' into 'master'
| | |\ \ \ \
| | | * | | | e449e08 (origin/revert-e275fc4c) Revert "Merge branch 'tasks-segment-export' into 'master'"
| | |/ / / /
| | * | | |   e275fc4 Merge branch 'tasks-segment-export' into 'master'
| | |\ \ \ \
| * | | | | | d76bad6 commit simple
* | | | | | | b874263 (origin/tmp-tasks-segment-export, tmp-tasks-segment-export) comment
| |_|_|_|_|/
|/| | | | |
* | | | | | 28fec5a correction
| |_|_|_|/
|/| | | |
* | | | | 361dbec tasks segment and template
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
* | | | b3f5d56 correct 2
* | | | e29c32d (new-task-name) correct export
| |_|/
|/| |
* | | c863e55 correct status search
* | | 2e46a2d task template ok
* | | 5040b30 first change
|/ /
* |   5a305e5 all merg
|\ \
| |/
| *   1cf4d74 Merge branch 'project-segments-templates' into 'master'
| |\
| | * deb460b (origin/project-segments-templates, project-segments-templates) segment deals ok
| | * 836b0a2 deal segment :number of tasks
| | * f4122bf template deals in progress
| | * 95cb825 segments OK
| | * 963e8d4 use mixins to move methods from company to ext file
| |/
* | 85c51b8 new
|/
*   1cf89e2 Merge branch 'export-template-update-detail-template-after-update-request' into 'master'
|\
| * b895ea2 (origin/export-template-update-detail-template-after-update-request, export-template-update-detail-template-after-update-request) work in progress
|/
*   cc4d145 Merge branch 'add-modifications-to-templates' into 'master'
|\
| * c594a16 (origin/add-modifications-to-templates, add-modifications-to-templates) public permission
| * a35ffbd move buttons to footer card
|/
*   272922c Merge branch 'add-public-segment-permission' into 'master'
```

Comment: One of the possible cases is that `tasks-segment-export` has been merged to `master` but the update changes are reverted on `master`.  What's the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master tasks-segment-export`? You can see if `master` is ahead of `tasks-segment-export`.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I updated this question with the gitlab graph

Comment: The error indicates that the repository has both a `master` branch and a `master` file. You could try `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master tasks-segment-export --` in this case. But from the graph we can already see that `tasks-segment-export` has been merged to `master`, so it's expected to see `Already up to date`. As for the missing changes on `master`, did you merge `tasks-segment-export` with the option `-X ours` or even `-s ours`? `-X ours` automatically takes our version for conflicts and `-s ours` merges only the history of `tasks-segment-export` without any of its changes.

Comment: okey, so do you want me to switch to master then : `git merge tasks-segment-export -s ours` ?

Comment: No, don't do it! I asked if you had done so, which could be the reason for the missing changes on `master`.

Comment: No I did not that ! even before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209097/discussion-between-mostafa-abdellaoui-and-elpiekay).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you already did the merge.  There is no more work to do.

(If you don't like the result of the merge, you can discard the commit from your `master`.  However, it's already been sent to another Git, and they will remember it by its hash ID, `0f5c91d`.  So if you don't like the result of the merge, you have to convince this other Git repository to discard *its* copy too, and then if anyone else has copied `0f5c91d` from the Git over at `origin`, you must get *them* to discard *their* copy, and so on.  Undoing a merge that's been distributed out to many other clones like this can be rather difficult.  It's often better to *revert* such a merge instead.  Re-doing the merge become a bit tricky, though.  It's not hard to *do* but it is hard to *explain*.)

---

This:

> ```
> $ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
> *   0f5c91d (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merge branch 'tasks-segment-export' into 'master'
> |\
> | * fbd2302 (origin/tasks-segment-export, tasks-segment-export) sc2
> * |   6e81272 (add-more-builders) head changes
> ```

shows that your branch name `tasks-segment-export` identifies commit `fbd2302`, which is already merged.  Your current branch `master` identifies commit `0f5c91d`, which is the result of this merge.

The *first parent* of merge commit `0f5c91d` is `6e81272`, which is the commit identified by your branch name `add-more-builders`.  The *second* parent of merge commit `0f5c91d` is commit `fbd2302`, which is identified by both your branch name `tasks-segment-export` and your remote-tracking name `origin/tasks-segment-export`.

Remember, Git is really all about *commits*.  Commits have parent/child relationships: children remember the raw hash ID of their parent or parent commits.  Branch names and remote-tracking names just serve to remember some *particular* commit.  A branch name remembers the commit hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.

Each commit can be in many branches simultaneously.  The set of branch names that allow you to *find* the commit, by starting at the tip commit of the branch and working backwards along the parent links, are the set of branches that contain the commit.  Since branch names can be added, deleted, or moved at any time, the *set of branch names* that contain any given commit can change!  The commit itself *never* changes, as long as you refer to it by raw hash ID.

To plant a name on a commit that *won't* automatically move or change, use a tag name.  That's what tag names are about: they identify some particular hash ID.  Hash IDs are random-looking and meaningless to humans, so we use branch names or tag names to *find* them.  The *branch* name automatically identifies the *last* commit of the branch, i.e., as we *add new commits*, the *branch name* updates automatically.  A *tag* name identifies one commit and stays there, i.e., as we add new commits, the *tag* stays put.

Comment: Thanks torek,, I did this and it works 
`git checkout tasks-segment-export`
`git merge --strategy=ours master`
`git checkout master`
`git merge tasks-segment-export`

Comment: Note that the `-s ours` means that your new merge commit on `tasks-segment-export` completely overrides whatever was in commit `0f5c91d` on `master`. If that's your desired result, that's fine.

Comment: yes exactly ! that's what I want , by the way do you  have any good tutorial I can learn more from it  ?

Comment: I don't, but [the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is worth reading.